# Is there a way to know if a notification is expanded or collapsed in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an expanded view notification. If the notification is at the top of notification drawer it is expanded otherwise collapsed. Is there any way to figure out whether the notification is expanded or collapsed while clicking.

Pressing the notification in collapsed and expanded view is not different.

Is there a native way to know if the notification is expanded or collapsed

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html ,"The big view of a notification only appears when the notification is expanded." so may be you can check if big view exists

Comment: Possible if android phone dont have MAX_PRIORITY (OEM Google or other app with cert). For normal app just setup :  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> AND mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);  (Use big or Big custum view)

Comment: Look at : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html Title : Applying an expanded layout to a notification